# Nested for loop with 'if' condition in Jinja2 template with html

Tags: python, html, css, jinja2

I am trying to write a Jinja Template within HTML and here is how it goes:

1. The list being passed from the Python Script is as follows:

```
    return render_template('index.html',
            table2_data = table2_data,
    )
```

table2_data is shown below:

```
[(1, 'T1', 'ST3', 'item1', datetime.date(2021, 2, 18), datetime.date(2021, 4, 23), '21.2', False, 'Approved', 'Windows', '2021', 2, 4),         
(2, 'T3', 'ST3', 'item2', datetime.date(2020, 12, 25), datetime.date(2021, 2, 25), '21.1', False, 'Draft', 'Windows', '2021', 12, 2), 
(3, 'T2', 'ST5', 'item3', datetime.date(2020, 12, 25), datetime.date(2021, 2, 25), '21.1', False, 'Approved', 'Linux', '2021', 12, 2), 
(4, 'T5', 'ST7', 'item4', datetime.date(2021, 11, 22), datetime.date(2022, 1, 22), '21.6', False, 'Approved', 'Windows', '2021', 11, 1), 
(5, 'T1', 'ST22', 'item5', datetime.date(2021, 7, 28), datetime.date(2021, 10, 28), '21.5', False, 'Approved', 'Linux', '2021', 7, 10), 
(6, 'T2', 'ST21', 'item6', datetime.date(2021, 4, 21), datetime.date(2021, 7, 21), '21.3', False, 'Approved', 'Windows', '2021', 4, 7), 
(7, 'T3', 'ST6', 'item7', datetime.date(2021, 4, 21), datetime.date(2021, 7, 21), '21.3', False, 'Approved', 'Linux', '2021', 4, 7), 
(8, 'T6', 'ST8', 'item8', datetime.date(2021, 7, 28), datetime.date(2021, 10, 28), '21.5', False, 'Rejected', 'Windows', '2021', 7, 10)]
```

2. HTML Code with Jinja where this list needs to be parsed is as follows:

```
        {% for items in table2_data %}
        <div class="chart-row">
          <div class="chart-row-item" style="background-color:#ee4035;" id="{{ items[2] }}">{{ items[2] }}</div>
            <ul class="chart-row-bars" style="background-color:#cdddd2;">
          {% for subtask in table2_data %}
            <li class="chart-li-dynamic" style="--columlength: {{subtask[11]}}/{{subtask[12]}};">{{ subtask[3] }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

My goal is to have 2 loops:

1. For the total number of row(which is equal to 8 in the sample).
2. The inner loop should only run to the count of items in items list which is at the 3rd index of the list.
   So for example 'ST3' has two items 'item1' & 'item2', hence the inner loop should only execute two times.
3. Also the data which would be shown in the list would come from the item list.
   So from the sample data, the expectation would be to create a 'chart-row-item' for each subtask(example ST3) and the list(chart-li-dynamic) should show each items(example for ST3 the list would be 'item1' & 'item2').

I am trying something like this. I am trying to create a Dynamic list but I am not sure if that is even possible.

```
<!--        {% for items in table2_data %}-->
<!--            {% set myList = [item for item in table2_data-->
<!--                       if item[1] == 'T1'] %}-->
<!--            {% for sub_items in myList %}-->
<!--        <div class="chart-row">-->
<!--          <div class="chart-row-item" style="background-color:#ee4035;" id="{{ myList[2] }}">{{ myList[2] }}</div>-->
<!--            <ul class="chart-row-bars" style="background-color:#cdddd2;">-->
<!--          {% for subtask in myList %}-->
<!--            <li class="chart-li-dynamic" style="&#45;&#45;columlength: {{subtask[11]}}/{{subtask[12]}};">{{ subtask[3] }}</li>-->
<!--            {% endfor %}-->
<!--                {% endfor %}-->
<!--            </ul>-->
<!--        </div>-->
<!--        {% endfor %}-->
<!--      </div>-->
```

Like in Python I can do it simply like this:

```
    Mytask1_suptask = [item for item in table2_data
                       if item[1] == 'T1']
```

Is there any way to implement this in Jinja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess

```
{% for item in table2_data %}
    {% if item[1] == 'T1' %}
        {{ item }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

---

(for clarity i am including the question that i was able to find in the OP's Question, below)

Like in Python I can do it simply like this:

```
Mytask1_suptask = [item for item in table2_data
                   if item[1] == 'T1']
```

Is there any way to implement this in Jinja.

---

you mention nested loops so maybe this is what you want

```
{% for item1 in table2_data %}
  <div>
    {% for item2 in table2_data %}
      {% if item1[1] == item2[1] %}
          {{ item }}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```